# How do I make some items in a paper-listbox one color and the other items another color depending on a property of the item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I have a `paper-listbox` with the `dom-repeat` template and each item in the listbox is a `paper-item`, like so:

```
<paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myList}}">
        <paper-item value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</paper-item>
    </template>
</paper-listbox>
```

Each item has a property, let's just call it `isValid`. What I would like to do is if `isValid === true` then set the background color of the corresponding `paper-item` element to white (which it is anyway, so probably nothing needs to be done in this case), and if `isValid === false`, then set the background color of the corresponding `paper-item` element to light blue.

In the .js file I populate an array with each item and then set that array to `myList`:

```
var i, len, item, items;
items = [];
for (i=0, len = results.length; i<len; i++) {
    item = results[i];
    items.push(_this.formatItem(item)); // formatItem initializes the item object so it
    // has things like item.name and item.isValid
}
_this.set("myList", items);
```

Sorry if any of the javascript looks weird -- I wrote it in coffeescript and copied the compiled javascript code. I am new to using Polymer and HTML/CSS/Javascript, so I'm not sure where to set the color. I think what is confusing me most is that the elements that I would like to change are inside the `dom-repeat` template of the `paper-listbox`, so I don't know how to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the CSS attribute selector with a value.

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp)

So in your case it would be:

```
paper-item[isValid="true"] {
    background: white;
}

paper-item[isValid="false"] {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xy00f48r/).

Or just create 1 style and set the default to white.

Comment: Thank you very much. There's one bit that isn't working for me. The binding of the `isValid` property of the item to the `isValid` attribute of the `paper-item` element doesn't seem to be working. I have `<paper-item value="{{item.name}}" isValid="{{item.isValid}}">` (plus the rest) but when I inspect the element that `isValid` attribute isn't there. I've also tried `isValid$="{{item.isValid}}"` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok I got it finally. What I believe was happening was that when `isValid === false` the item was removing the attribute from the element. Now in my javascript I converted the boolean to a string. Now it looks like: `<paper-item value="{{item.name}}" isValid$="[[item.isValid]]">` etc.